# AMFPHP overiding default function arguments?

Tags: argument-passing, amfphp

I've got this odd problem.

If I make a call on that function through amfphp service browser and give it a valid ID and leave the `$num_images` field blank amfphp will actually pass a blank string as the argument.

```
// if i call this function width just an ID
function getWorkers($id, $num_images = 100) {
    ...
    // num_images will be set as ''
}
```

I can easily override using a check:

```
function getWorkers($id, $num_images = 100) {
    if($num_images=='') $num_images = 100;
    ...
    // num_images will now be really set as 100
}
```

Anyone experiencing the same with amfphp?

Comment: That's odd, I never got that from AMFPHP. If you don't have the latest version try updating your installation of AMFPHP.

Also make sure Flash doesn't somehow pass an empty variable as the second variable.

Comment: @Francisc yep, thats the case, AMFPHP browser (the one that lets you access all the webservices in a pretty interfaces) always passes an empty string as a variable when one is not input. Odd. But easy to solve nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. :)

Comment: @Francisc in SO fashion you could put up your comment as an answer so I can accept it (makes more sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd, I never got that from AMFPHP. If you don't have the latest version try updating your installation of AMFPHP. Also make sure Flash doesn't somehow pass an empty variable as the second variable.

(Copied from the comment.)